# Проблема с запятой

Tags: python-3.x

Такой код:

```
from subprocess import check_output

b = check_output(["wmic", "product get name,version"])
```

Ловлю такую ошибку:

```
"product get name - Alias not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "n.py", line 3, in <module>
    check_output(["wmic", "product get name,version"])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 223, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['wmic', 'product get name,version']' re
turned non-zero exit status 44135
```

Я думал что проблема в этой части:  `"product get name,version"` (но мои попытки исправить были не успешны)
В чем проблема?

Comment: `["wmic", "product", "get", "name,version"]`

Comment: Спасибо, заработало.